# Getting Refresh token error in auth0-nextjs application

Tags: node.js, reactjs, authentication, next.js, auth0

We are building a web application (Single page application)using NextJS. In which we are using auth0 for login. We are facing weird problem, after login we are getting an error message saying
`Error: A refresh token is required to refresh the access token, but none is present.`
[image: Error message in browser]

We have `getAccessToken.js` file where we have added all the necessary configs to get the token but still getting the error.

```
const afterRefresh = (req, res, session) => {
    console.log("sess", session);
    delete session.idToken;
    return session;
};
export default async function MyHandler(req, res) {
    const token = await getAccessToken(req, res, {
        refresh: true,
        afterRefresh,
    });
```

also we are setting `scope` as `offline` in `[...auth0].ts` file

```
export default handleAuth({
    async login(req, res) {
        try {
            await handleLogin(req, res, {
                authorizationParams: {
                    audience: "gateway.dev.abcdDomain.com",
                    // Add the `offline_access` scope to also get a Refresh Token
                    scope: "openid profile email offline_access", // or AUTH0_SCOPE
                    useRefreshTokens: true,
                },
            });
        } catch (error) {
            res.status(error.status || 400).end(error.message);
        }
    },
```

The `get-access-token.ts` in nextjs-auth0 library, the `accessTokenRequest` is Boolean

```
export interface AccessTokenRequest {
  /**
   * A list of desired scopes for your Access Token.
   */
  scopes?: string[];
  /**
   * If set to `true`, a new Access Token will be requested with the Refresh Token grant, regardless of whether
   * the Access Token has expired or not.
   */
  refresh?: boolean;
```

any idea where we are going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `offline_access` from the scope & line - `useRefreshTokens: true,`

It should be inserted when you have refresh token enabled in auth0 dashboard. Otherwise don't include it.

Ref:
https://auth0.com/docs/secure/tokens/refresh-tokens/refresh-token-rotation